# How to manage pre-existing and changing redux state in react functional components, or stop previous data loading again

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a pretty complex form backed by a large state object, which can start off blank, but can also be loaded from a data store. The problem is that although the correct id is brought in from `useParams()` (so the routing seems ok), and the right data is fetched, it seems as if the state does not get updated (or updated in time) and the previous data is loaded.

In the following code, the `console.log()` statements are in the `useEffect()` function. Compare these to the image of the console output...

```ts
export const SimpleTabs = () => {

  const charstate = useAppSelector(state => state.charstate);
  const userstate = useAppSelector(state => state.userstate);
  const specstate = useAppSelector(state => state.specState);
  
  const getCurrentUser = (): string => {
    return userstate.loggedInUser?.username as string
  }
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { id } = useParams();
  
  const [data, setData] = useState(makeEmptyCharFromUser(getCurrentUser()));
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const refreshCache = async (type: string) => {
    await dispatch(fetchSpecs({ foundry: 'chars', type: type}))
  }

  const loadSpecs = (type: string) => {
    const cached = getSpecsByType(type, specstate.specKeys);
    if (cached.length === 0) {
      refreshCache(type);

    } else {
      let refresh = cached.find(se => addHoursToDate(new Date(se.at), TTL).getTime() > Date.now())
  
      if (refresh) {
        refreshCache(type);
      }
    }
    
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(id)
    setLoading(true);
    if (id) {
      const f = async(id:string) => {
        await dispatch(fetchChar(id));
        setData(charstate.char as Char);
      }
      f(id);
    
    } else {
      // set with the blank state
      setData(makeEmptyCharFromUser(getCurrentUser()))
    }
    loadSpecs(TYPE_SKILL_DEF);
    loadSpecs(TYPE_QUALITY);
    loadSpecs(TYPE_SOPHONT);
    loadSpecs(TYPE_ENHANCEMENT);
    loadSpecs(TYPE_WEAPON);
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(charstate.char)
    console.log(data)

    if (charstate.selectedTabIndex === undefined) {
      dispatch(setSelectedTabIndex(0));
    }
  
  }, [id]);



  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, newValue: number) => {
    dispatch(setSelectedTabIndex(newValue));
  };

  const onSubmit = async (
    data: Partial<Char>
  ) => {
    if (charstate.char && charstate.char.id) {
      await dispatch(editChar(data));
    } else {
      // its a new char, so create 

      await dispatch(createChar(data));
    }
  };


  return loading ? (
    <p>Loading...</p>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <ThemeProvider theme={strikerTheme}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={charstate.selectedTabIndex}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="character creation steps"
        >
          <Tab label="Description" />
          <Tab label="Sophontcy" />
          <Tab label="Professions" />
          <Tab label="Abilities" />
          <Tab label="Backgrounds" />
          <Tab label="Skills" />
          <Tab label="Enhancements" />
          <Tab label="Equipment" />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={0}>
        <DescriptionForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={1}>
        <SophontcyForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={2}>
        <ProfessionsForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={3}>
        <AbilitiesForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={4}>
        <BackgroundsForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={5}>
        <SkillsForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={6}>
        <EnhancementsForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel selectedTabIndex={charstate.selectedTabIndex} tabIndex={7}>
        <EquipmentForm onSubmit={onSubmit} data={data} />
      </TabPanel>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The console output is:

[image: TabGroup.tsx log output]

The first console.log() in the code is line 84 in the console.

Note how the id changes from a32c6996-a961-4d16-b5d2-cd5429dd93b2 (correct) to 552d5d79-bd27-4505-9833-9b06c2994c20 in line 103.

So charstate.char still has the old state. Note that the call `dispatch(fetchChar(id))` is awaited. So doesn't that mean that the results of that call are resolved before moving on to the `setData(...)` call? why then does the following console output (line 104), which should be the readout of the data, present an empty object?

As you can see I really don't understand the lifecycles, I have read a lot of doco on the subject, but my code seems to be doing something different to what the doco suggests. What am i doing wrong here?